# How to open PhpMyAdmin on Mac?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm new to PHP & MYSQL.

I've installed MAMP on OSX lion, 
I can't open PhpMyAdmin in my browser "Safari".

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit

I get URL NOT FOUND

The problem is that I can't figure out the correct URL !!!

Comment: What do you mean by "can't open"? What's the error message? Can you open other PHP file? More information please?

Comment: Tried this answer yet? http://superuser.com/questions/114221/how-can-i-start-phpmyadmin

Comment: This question is related to configuring MySQL/Apache/PhpMyAdmin, but not really a programming question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd seriously recommend the free [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) instead – it has the same functionality, but is a million times nicer to use.